# Web Listener Configuration modified dynamically

Tags: java, jsf, weblogic, listener

Need to have a configuration screen for my listener.
Now I want to start and stop the MyListener from web application.
Sample listener in web.xml

```
<listener>
  com.sample.MyListener
</listener>
```

**JSF framework

Weblogic 9.2 & higher**

Comment: Are you sure you want to write a web application?

Comment: Yes please, the web application is an existing one which has around 24 listener. in the web-app we use listener as web scheduler.

Comment: You'll probably need to give more details about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far before anyone can give you an answer.

Comment: Kindly omit my previous comment We used listener as scheduler to do the back-end job. we used to configure the scheduler class as I have specified above since there was no requirement to control these scheduler from the application Current requirement users wants to control these scheduler, I don't want to change the current architecture as it won't be feasible with requirement  I wanted to know if its possible to change the configuration of the web.xml and apply without restarting the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've indicated that you don't want to change the current architecture, but I'd definitely recommend looking at something like Quartz (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to manage your job scheduling, and initialize that via one individual lifecycle listener.

It may be possible to go and poke listener configuration in the bowels of your web application at runtime, but you're going to end up creating a rod for your own back in terms of the complexity, and recreating a lot of the concepts that already exist there.

You'll make life a lot easier by using a framework like that which (from memory) exposes either EJB or JMX-based configuration allowing you to make configuration changes at runtime.

That way you won't need to potentially redeploy your application in order to have changes take effect.